# PHP - mySQL db keeps ingoring 1st part of my query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hello i wrote some PHP code:

```
$number = $_POST['number'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$validation_query = "SELECT * FROM `rezerwacje_miejsc` WHERE 
`NR_MIEJSCA`='$number' AND `START` BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' OR `KONIEC` 
BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end';";
```

But every time SQL is returning any value if is between but ignores number - I've tried to use '$number', $number or even wrote number manually. Still no effect any ideas?

Comment: try to use   " + $number + "  Did you try echoing and manually executing the sql query?

Comment: Is the a record that matches the value of `$number`?

Comment: can you please try by adding braces to your query like
"SELECT * FROM `rezerwacje_miejsc` WHERE 
`NR_MIEJSCA`='$number' AND (`START` BETWEEN ('$start' AND '$end') OR `KONIEC` 
BETWEEN ('$start' AND '$end'));"

Comment: it finds all records that BETWEEN values are true no matter what the number is - it is just like if there was no `NR_MIEJSCA`=$number only further BETWEEN

Comment: @ikdekker why + ?

Comment: the way he put it, it seemed like it may have been interpreted as a string literal. Closing the string adding a var with concatenation could make it more legible too imo

Comment: `.` is  concatenation operator for PHP and  `+`  is for Javascript

Comment: haha i see, have adapted to other languages. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is beacause of your "AND".
I will short the SQL a little bit to explain it better:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1 AND condition2 OR condition3
```

This will simply link the three conditions together. So if your Condition3 is true, Condition1 & Condition2 doesn't matter.

I think if you use brackets it could work:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition1 AND (condition2 OR condition3)
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: That was exactly my issue. Thanks I'll rember this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$number = (int)$_POST['number'];

$validation_query = "SELECT * FROM `rezerwacje_miejsc` WHERE 
`NR_MIEJSCA`=".$number." AND (`START` BETWEEN ('$start' AND '$end') OR `KONIEC` 
BETWEEN ('$start' AND '$end'))";
```

You need to pass the integer value. Secondly you need to () so it will read the query to satisfied both conditions  `NR_MIEJSCA`=".$number." And `START` BETWEEN ('$start' AND '$end') OR `KONIEC` 
BETWEEN ('$start' AND '$end'))" but OR condition on the second part.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.